# Visual Studio 2008 C++ won't compile changes in header class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, compilation

I have a very strange problem in Visual C++ 2008:

My project contains some classes which I'm developping and I'm not including to precompiled header stdafx.h as they are not still finished (**EDIT** they are included in the main.cpp file, after stdafx.h)

When I make changes in a class which has .h and .cpp files, the changes are applied correctly.

When I make changes in a class which only has a .h file, VC2008 detects errors in there, but if all goes right, it runs the program and the class is not updated. A prove of this is that if I set a breakpoint somewhere in the class, it doesn't stop there and the breakpoint appears with a warning saying that "there is no executable code associated with this line".

**EDIT** I tried to include the header file in stdafx.h and the behaviour is the same: changes are not applied.

What I'm doing right now is to clean the project before running again. Sometimes I loose lots of time if I forgot to clean because I have to reach large process to reach and test the changes, then I see I can't debug and have to stop, clean, run and reach changes!

Any solution to not have to clean the project once and again?

Comment: You can't debug code that isn't included in the current executable you are running. When you say VS2008 detects errors, do you mean the intellisense detects errors? I would find it very strange if the compiler was giving you errors on code you're not including in the project.

Comment: The code is included for sure, as I reach breakpoints there and the code of the file is running. When I say VS2008 detect errors I mean at compile time

Answer (score 0):

Just for curiosity I went deeper in this issue. Very weird behaviour:

When changes are made only in a private class member function from a header class with no .cpp file, which is included in stdafx.h (precompiled), then compiler won't apply changes!!

This won't apply if changes are made in the constructor, public methods, variable or in sub-struct/class definitions.

If this makes sense for someone it would be really good a clear explanation.